# Where do temporary files go while installing a .deb package?

Tags: dpkg

I am creating a .deb package that needs a MySQL database. I am building the package using `dpkg-deb --build`. While installing I want my post install script to execute an SQL script to set up the database like so:

```
cat setup.sql | mysql -u root -p
```

I am currently putting setup.sql into the "DEBIAN" folder of my package. What path do I need to specify in my post install script to find this SQL script?

I know I could embed the SQL contents into my post-install script but I want to keep them separate for code maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t easily (if at all) access files you add to `DEBIAN` in a package built with `dpkg-deb -b` — those files end up in the control information area of the binary package, they aren’t installed as such (in fact, I’m not sure non-standard files are even included in the package; standard files end up in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`).

You should instead install your script in `/usr/share/yourpackage` (replacing `yourpackage` with the name of your package). Then your `postinst` can access it there.

*Ideally*, you’d use [`dbconfig-common`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/dbconfig-common/) instead; that supports a wide variety of use-cases and database configurations. It would involve more work up-front but would result in a much more versatile package.

Comment: I ended up with something similar, creating a folder <install root>/install with the bits and pieces I needed and then deleting them in the `postinst` script. Is `/usr/share/<name/` a more standard location? Should I be tidying up after installation or leaving them there?

Comment: `/usr/share/package` is yours to do what you want in, and yes, that’s the standard location for such files. You should leave them alone, `postinst` shouldn’t delete files which are shipped in a package.

Comment: If the "setup.sql" really is not properly part of the installed package, maybe instead of a separate file, you should include the text in postinst. pass it to mysql with echo instead of cat