# Debian: resource file for use in postinst

Tags: deb

I am trying to build a Debian package which installs a database (the DBMS is a dependency, this package makes sure a certain database is present). I would like `postinst` to take care of initializing the database with a schema, for which I have prepared a .sql file. This .sql script is only needed during installation; I do not see a need to keep it around afterwards.

How would I include such a script (or any resource file needed only by `postinst`) in a package? (Initializing the DB with the script is not the issue, as long as I know where the script resides.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install it as part of the package’s contents, somewhere like `/usr/share/yourpackage`. Files needed by `postinst` should be kept around in general, because your `postinst` might be used again after the first time it’s run (*e.g.* following a `dpkg-reconfigure`)... There’s no provision for deleting files shipped by a package (`dpkg` expects them to stay).

See also [Where do temporary files go while installing a .deb package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404758/86440) and the `dbconfig-common` suggestion in my answer there.